# wrapping around minutes into hours

Tags: java

I'm doing simple clock which wraps around when reaching 0 (e.g 00:59 -> 01:00, 23:59 -> 00:00). I got stuck at this moment and can't figure it out.
I have to do this in this way, using just methods given in 'BoundedCounter' class.

```
public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BoundedCounter minutes = new BoundedCounter(59, 0);
        BoundedCounter hours = new BoundedCounter(23, 0);

        int i = 0;

        while (i < 70) { //repeats actual time 70 times - just to check if works fine

            //put code here
            i++;
        }

    }

}
```

.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class BoundedCounter {

private int startValue;
private int upperLimit;
private int value;

public BoundedCounter(int upperLimit, int startValue) {
    this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
    this.startValue = startValue;
    this.value = startValue;
}

public void next() {

    value++;
    if (value > upperLimit) {
        value = 0;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#00");
    return "" + df.format(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the specific issue? Seems like you should be calling `next` on your `BoundedCounter` at some point, and doing some sort of check to see if your minutes have rolled over.

Comment: Thats the point I have no idea how to do it. It's always something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One variant is to use handlers:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BoundedCounter minutes = new BoundedCounter(59, 0);
        final BoundedCounter hours = new BoundedCounter(23, 0);

        minutes.setOverflow(hours::next);
        hours.setOverflow(minutes::reset);

        for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) { //repeats actual time 70 times - just to check if works fine
            minutes.next();
            System.out.println(hours.toString() + ":" + minutes.toString());
        }
    }

    public static class BoundedCounter {
        private int startValue;
        private int upperLimit;
        private int value;
        private Runnable c;

        public BoundedCounter(int upperLimit, int startValue) {
            this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
            this.startValue = startValue;
            this.value = startValue;
        }

        public void reset() {
            this.value = startValue;
        }

        public void setOverflow(final Runnable c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void next() {
            if (++value > upperLimit) {
                value = 0;
                c.run();
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#00");
            return "" + df.format(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the teacher might raise an eyebrow at this approach.

Comment: @DaveNewton what exactly is strange? usage of delegates/handlers?

Comment: Nothing-just using techniques far above the OP's current level.

Comment: @DaveNewton ah, actually I believe this approach is easier to understand for OP, neither trying to give correct variant, where only time in minutes is stored and hour/minutes separation is only matter of toString presentation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help... To show current time use:

```
System.out.println(hours.toString() + ":" + minutes.toString());
```

To increment hours: `hours.next()`

To increment minutes: `minutes.next()`